# Haskell Functions (map,foldr, foldl)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sum, fold, foldleft

I am struggling to think of a way to utilize these functions for this beginner level coding class that I am taking to learn functional programming in Haskell. The functions I have to write are shown below, `asum` is supposed to turn a list of integers `[a1,a2,..,an]` into the alternating sum `a1-a2+a3-a4+.…` and I am not sure how to approach it with these functions. The `xor` function is supposed to that computes the XOR of a list of Booleans. I need some help to understand how to use these functions and it would greatly appreciated. I am also new to Haskell so any explanations would help. Thanks I have to use `map foldr foldl`.

```
asum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a

xor :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say start by running the following, one by one, in `GHCi`:

```
:t foldr
:info foldr
:doc foldr

:t foldl
:info foldl
:doc foldl

:t map
:info map
:doc map
```

Or better, open [hoogle.haskell.org](https://hoogle.haskell.org) and search each of the above mentioned functions and click on the first link.

But I agree that Haskell documentation are difficult to read, especially for beginners. I'm a beginner and I have a lot of difficulty reading and understanding them.

Here's a function that uses `map` and `foldr` to show how `foldr` works:

```hs
printFoldr xs = foldr (\x acc -> "(" ++ x ++ " + " ++ acc ++ " )") "0"  $ map  show xs
```

Now running watch this:

```hs
printFoldr [1..5]
-- outputs the following:
"(1 + (2 + (3 + (4 + (5 + 0 ) ) ) ) )"
```

This shows us how `foldr` is evaluated. Before going into how `foldr` is evaluated, let's look briefly at `map`.

```hs
map show [1..5]
-- outputs the following:
["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

This means that `map` takes 2 arguments. A list and a function that is applied to each element of the list. The result is a new list with the function applied to each element. Thus, applying `show` to each number outputs their string representation.

Back to `foldr`. `foldr` takes 3 arguments:

1. a function of type `a -> b -> b`
2. an initial value of type `b`
3. a list of type `[a]`

`foldr` takes each and every value of the provided list and applies this function to it. What is special is that map retains the output of the function over each iteration and passes it to the function as its second argument on the next run. Therefore it is convenient to write the function that is passed `foldr` as follows: `(\el acc -> do something)`. Now on the next iteration of `foldr`, `acc` will hold the value of the previous run and `el` will be the current element from the list. BTW, `acc` stands for accumulator and `el` for element. This enables us to reduce elements of the provided list to something completely new.

As you can see in `printFoldr`, the initial value is just an empty string but it gradually adds the lists elements to it showing how it would have reduced the elements of the list to their sum.

Comment: True, thank you for pointing that out. Going to put "0" there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea:

```
a1-a2+a3-a4+...
=
a1-(a2-(a3-(a4-(...(an-0)...))))
```

This fits pretty well to the `foldr` pattern of recursion,

```
foldr f z [a1,a2,a3,a4,...,an]
=
a1`f`(a2`f`(a3`f`(a4`f`(...(an`f`z)...))))
```

So it can be coded by setting `f = ...` and `z = ...` and calling

```
asum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
asum xs = foldr f z xs
  where
  f = (...)
  z = (...)
```

You will need to complete this definition.

---

For the `XOR` of a list of Booleans, assuming it is to be `True` if one and only one of them is `True`, and `False` otherwise, we can imagine this sequence of transformations:

```
[ True, False, False, True, True, False, ...]
==>
[ t,    f,     f,     t,    t,    f,     ...]
```

where `t` and `f` are some specially chosen numbers. And then we can find the sum of this second list (not alternating sum, just a sum of a list of numbers) and check whether it is equal to ... some (other?) special number, let's call it `n1`:

```
xor :: [Bool] -> Bool
xor bools  =  (aNumber ... n1)
  where
    list1 = bools
    list2 = fun1 transform list1
    transform False = f
    transform True  = t
    f = ...
    t = ...
    aNumber = sum list2
    n1 = ...
    fun1 = ...
    sum listOfNums = ...
```

`fun1` is the function which transforms each element of its argument list according to the given function, called `transform` above. It is one of the two functions left from the three you were given, considering we've already been using `foldr`.

`sum` is to be implemented by using the last function that's left.

FYI,

```
map foo [a1,a2,a3,...,an]
=
[foo a1, foo a2, foo a3, ..., foo an]
```

and

```
foldl f z [a1,a2,a3,...,an]
=
((((z`f`a1)`f`a2)`f`a3)...)`f`an
```

Comment: I am puzzled by the XOR part, it looks rather complex. Can't we just fold a binary XOR?

Comment: @chi wouldn't ``True`xor`True`xor`True`` with a simple `xor` return `True` instead of `False`? so we'd need a rather complex `xor` then. no? I might miss something obvious, too. in any case my approach seems rather simple to me, and it makes use of both remaining functions. I've just written out a lot of steps explicitly to match my description. it also has a kind of newbie-oriented quality to it, I thought.

Comment: Thanks, I sort of understand the first part and the f = (...) that would be f = (-) and z = (0) right, or am I misunderstanding

Comment: yes, correct. the next step is to decide what is `fun1`.

Comment: @WillNess I would indeed expect `xor [True,True,True]` to be true. XOR is essentially sum modulo 2, which is associative, so it can be folded. I can't think of any different notion of "XOR over `[Bool]`", but you seem to have one in mind.

Comment: @chi oh, of course, _over_ the list it is so; but the question asks for "XOR **of** a list of Booleans". that was the only interpretation I could come up with, the one in my answer (xor of 2 values is true if only one is true... then simply change 2 --> N).  ...... XOR seems commutative as well, so your interpretation does make sense too.

Comment: @chi thinking this over my take on it discriminates unfairly towards the True. "xor" means they are "all different" so the mirror interpretation would be "False when just one element is False" and there's no choosing between the two. oh well. but actually 1. the is a _programming_ exercise and 2. the two interpretations have the same implementation! just need to exchange the `t` and `f` values. :) so if we want to be cheeky we abstract over the t and the f, and get just one lambda function as _one_ solution. like Church.